# How to loop at a dynamic internal table?

Tags: abap

I'm working on an Enhancement Implantation on ZXMBCU10 which is called in a custom program couple of levels down the execution path. Inside ZXMBCU10 I want to access the a table in the parent program, which I do in the following method;

1. Declare the parent program name;

   `DATA: ex_tbl_name TYPE char100 VALUE '(ZPROGRAM)G_TAB'.`
2. Getting the value through field symbol assignment.

   `FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs> TYPE any.`

   `ASSIGN (ex_tbl_name) TO <fs>.`

Then I check for successful assignment (which is true).

```
IF <fs> IS ASSIGNED.
```

[image: Accessing parent table]

Problem I have is how to read the data in the `<fs>` field symbol.

I've tried LOOP and READ TABLE, but getting the following;

[image: Loop and Read table sample]

*Both Read Table and Loop is added here just to get the syntax checks*

**LOOP;**

Internal table "`<FS>`" has no header line - one of the additions "INTO
wa", "ASSIGNING", "REFERENCE INTO", "TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS" required.
required.

**READ TABLE;**

You cannot use explicit or implicit index operations on tables with
types "HASHED TABLE" or "ANY TABLE". "`<FS>`" has the type "ANY TABLE".
It is possible that the "TABLE" addition was not specified before
"`<FS>`".

Comment: Based on your description, it's impossible to get the message you show for `LOOP AT`. Could you provide a compilable code so that your issue can be reproduced. Thank you. (PS: the message you get for `READ TABLE` corresponds to your description)

Comment: I agree with @SandraRossi. There is not enough information on the question to derive the solution.

Comment: @SandraRossi and Umar Abdullah i've updated the question. Hope that it's more clearer now.

Comment: @isuru Thanks. What I meant is just a copy/paste of your LOOP AT code to [help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sorry to have said "compilable" because it's not relevant in your case, so help us reproduce the syntax error.

Comment: @SandraRossi added the rest of the code. I've written both the Read table and the loops, just to get the syntax error thrown. Thanks a bunch for the continued interest :)

Comment: @isuru Thanks. It's better if you paste the text, not an image, so that it's easier to reproduce the problem by copying & pasting the text.

Answer (score 4):

**LOOP AT**

The error about `LOOP AT` (*Internal table "`<FS>`" has no header line - one of the additions "INTO wa", "ASSIGNING", "REFERENCE INTO", "TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS" required*), is that you don't indicate the "result" part of `LOOP AT` i.e. ASSIGNING, REFERENCE INTO... (as said in the message).

For a field symbol, LOOP AT **alone** is always invalid, and if it's a variable instead of a field symbol it's obsolete because that would imply the use of a header line.

```
LOOP AT <fs>. " always invalid !
```

A valid syntax could be as follows: you must declare the field symbol as being an internal table (with at least the word `TABLE`, or refer to a "Table Type"), any category of internal table is supported for LOOP AT (hashed, sorted, standard), so you can use `TYPE ANY TABLE` :

```
DATA: ex_tbl_name TYPE char100 VALUE '(ZPROGRAM)G_TAB'.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs> TYPE ANY TABLE.

ASSIGN (ex_tbl_name) TO <fs>.
LOOP AT <fs> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
ENDLOOP.
```

**READ TABLE**

The error about `READ TABLE` (*You cannot use explicit or implicit index operations on tables with types "HASHED TABLE" or "ANY TABLE". "`<FS>`" has the type "ANY TABLE". It is possible that the "TABLE" addition was not specified before "`<FS>`"*) is that you used `READ TABLE ... INDEX ...` whose INDEX means that it can only be used with an internal table with category `SORTED` or `STANDARD`.

The next code is invalid because of the combination of ANY TABLE and READ TABLE INDEX, because `<FS>` could eventually be a *hashed* internal table (who knows), then READ TABLE INDEX would fail, hence the compiler error:

```
DATA: ex_tbl_name TYPE char100 VALUE '(ZPROGRAM)G_TAB'.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs> TYPE ANY TABLE. " <=== impossible with READ TABLE INDEX !

ASSIGN (ex_tbl_name) TO <fs>.
READ TABLE <fs> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>) INDEX 1. " <=== impossible with ANY TABLE !
```

Solution: to use `READ TABLE <fs> INDEX ...` you may declare the field-symbol as SORTED, STANDARD, or INDEX (the latter is a generic name corresponding to SORTED and STANDARD).

This code is valid:

```
DATA: ex_tbl_name TYPE char100 VALUE '(ZPROGRAM)G_TAB'.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs> TYPE INDEX TABLE.

ASSIGN (ex_tbl_name) TO <fs>.
READ TABLE <fs> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>) INDEX 1.
```

Of course, it's assumed that G_TAB is an "index" table, not a hashed table!

PS: in your code you used `INTO DATA(lv_fs)` but usually if you have a generic internal table `ASSIGNING` is preferred.

Comment: using both these methods I'm able to reference the lines in the G_TAB, but the issue now come in accessing it. When I call the columns in the table using <line>-colName in both access methods (Loops and Read), I'm getting the syntax error; Field "<LINE>-MBLNR" is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement. "DATA" statement.

The filed does exists.  https://imgur.com/a/2hekdJY

Comment: @Isuru add: ASSIGN COMPONENT 'MBLNR' OF STRUCTURE <fs> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_mblnr>).

Comment: @isuru in fact the title of the question says all, but your question focused only on the first part of the topic. Can you extend the question please to focus on the main problem (which is global in fact)? I think it's worth an additional answer to explain the whole logic, without details of the collateral issues. Moreover, I presume that the type of the internal table G_TAB is defined statically in ZPROGRAM, so you could make its type global (via an interface-pool type or a DDIC type), and you could define the field symbol based on this type.

Answer (score 3):

change field symbol type to

```
any table.
```

instead of:

```
any.
```

Comment: I realize that it solves the issue for LOOP AT, but not for READ TABLE because it's an access with `INDEX`. So, if both statements are used in the same procedure, `FIELD-SYMBOLS <FS> TYPE INDEX TABLE` should be used.